# Clear cache for PHP syntax checking

Tags: php

At the company I work we use Jenkins to CI our PHP code. We also use PHP CLI syntax checking to see if there are any syntax errors. Command us:

`$ php -l`

When a file is new or edited and this file contains an error, PHP correctly returns an error. When run a second time, this file is cached somehow, and the error doesn't show again. Is there a way to clear this cache?

Comment: Cached where? How is the command run? PHP certainly doesn't cache it.

Comment: The command is run in my source folder: ` $ php -l <PATH>`. From the php manual:
--syntax-check
-l             Syntax check only (lint)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:
The command was generated through an Ant build script. That script cached the result of `php -l`, because of the `<modified />` tag in build.xml file.